# Why will Firefox not measure the length of this SVG path

Tags: javascript, firefox, svg

SVG:

```
<g fill="none" stroke-width="0.6">
    <path id="trouble" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke="#ff5500" d="M1051.19,607.23c3.8-1.9,4.1,4.9,3.5,7c-0.7,2.3-2.6,4.6-5.3,3.8c-3.9-1.1-4.4-6.9-4-10.1c0.8-7.2,7.2-10.7,12.2-4.4c4.1,5.2,5.4,15.4,4.7,21.8c-0.5,4.4-3.3,10.4-8.8,8.1c-4.6-1.9-4.4-9.8-0.1-11.9c7.9-3.8,4.5,12.1-0.3,6.8"/>
</g>
```

Chrome and Firefox both paint the little red squiggle correctly. Chrome measures the path length correctly using `path.getTotalLength()`. Firefox returns `NaN` for the path length. Why?

(I have dozens of other paths that Firefox measures the length of correctly. There's something about this path in particular, generated using Illustrator. The syntax looks correct to me AFAIK.)

See:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oXpqqg

Comment: Probably https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1134549 there's a patch there that should land fairly soon.

Comment: Thanks Robert. The thing is, my coordinates aren't anywhere near as large as in Klaus's testcase in that bug. Hmm.

Comment: Download the source, apply the patch and see if that fixes your problem. If it does, great, if not raise a bug in bugzilla.

Comment: I asked the author of the above patch to test if it fixes this bug. He confirmed it does.  Hopefully the fix will make it into FF soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you tweak the path slightly to work around [the FF bug](http://%20bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1134549) you can make it work.

There is one curve that seems to trigger the bug:

```
c0.8-7.2,7.2-10.7,12.2-4.4
```

if you change that slightly, the bug is avoided:

```
c0.9-7.2,7.2-10.7,12.2-4.4
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NqyKwP)

Comment: Thank you Paul--I really appreciate the prompt attention to this. Unfortunately my application involves arbitrary paths, in large quantities, so hand-tweaking the offending elements isn't practical. Hope to see this land in Nightly ASAP.